# How to grab text between multiple occurrences of tags?

Tags: php, regex

i have this description that holds users mention tag.

**[MENTION=1]one[/MENTION][MENTION=4]two[/MENTION][MENTION=748]three[/MENTION] HI, it is me!!**

i need to know who is the members that are mentioned in this description,so i expect.

```
['one','two','three']
```

here is what i have tried:

```
preg_match_all('/[MENTION=[1-9]](.*?)[\/MENTION]/s', $html, $matches);
if($matches) print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
[
  [0] => one[
  [1] =>  [
  [2] => two[
  [3] =>  [
  [4] => three[
  [5] =>  H
]
```

*What if i need to get the numbers 1,4,748 ?*

Comment: Add parenthesis around the [1-9] to capture them. Eg 'MENTION=([1-9])'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets are reserved characters in a RegEx. You need to escape them. Something like this should work:

```
preg_match_all('/\[MENTION=([1-9]+)\](.*?)\[\/MENTION\]/s', $html, $matches);
```

I've also added a capture group around the IDs,`([1-9]+)`, so you get the numeric values and the text-content in your matches (`$matches[1]` will contain the numbers and `$matches[2]` will contain the text-contents).

Answer (score 2):

`(\d+)` capturing group for 1 or more numbers

`(\w+)` capturing group for 1 or more word characters

as you know from `[1-9]` that the square brackets `[]` are special characters in regex that denote character sets. so if you literally want to match one of those, then you'll have to escape them with backslashes `\[\]`

```
<?php

$html = '[MENTION=1]one[/MENTION][MENTION=4]two[/MENTION][MENTION=748]three[/MENTION] HI, it is me!!';

preg_match_all('/\[MENTION=(\d+)\](\w+)\[\/MENTION\]/s', $html, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => [MENTION=1]one[/MENTION]
>             [1] => [MENTION=4]two[/MENTION]
>             [2] => [MENTION=748]three[/MENTION]
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 1
>             [1] => 4
>             [2] => 748
>         )
>
>     [2] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => one
>             [1] => two
>             [2] => three
>         )
>
> )
> ```